# Null values not being removed from pandas dataframe when using notnull() in a filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv where the dataframe looks like this:

| DataType | Type 1 Data | Type 2 Data | TypeEtc Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type 1 | 15.1 |  |  |
| Type 2 |  | 45.3 |  |
| TypeEtc |  |  | 53.5 |
| Type 2 |  | 12.0 |  |
| Type 1 |  |  |  |
| TypeEtc |  |  | 12.8 |

I import in Python and am trying to run some filters to remove null values. Importantly however, if DataType is Type 1, then values in "Type 2 Data" and "TypeEtc Data" column can be null/blank, since they will never have readings, but if the DataType is Type1 and the entry in "Type 1 Data" is null/blank then I want the whole row to be removed. I also need the values to be above 0 so any negative and 0 values get removed. I've tried using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file/path/unfiltered.csv)
filter1= (df['DataType'] == 'Type 1') & (df['Type 1 Data'].notnull()) & (df['Type 1 Data'] > 0)
filter2= (df['DataType'] == 'Type 2') & (df['Type 2 Data'].notnull()) & (df['Type 2 Data'] > 0)
filteretc = (df['DataType'] == 'TypeEtc') & (df['TypeEtc Data'].notnull()) & (df['TypeEtc Data'] > 0)

filtered_df = df[filter1 | filter 2 | filteretc]

filtered_df.tocsv(file/path/filtered.csv)
```

The output of this is identical to the input CSV. I've tried just using one filter, and it still changed nothing. To confirm I do still have blanks and values =< 0 I opened the CSV in excel and filtered manually and indeed I can see there are multiple blank, 0 and negative values for each columns data type when filtered by type.

I'm guessing it's something to do with how my filters are set up but can't think what to change

Comment: those might be empty stings and not really ```nan``` ?

Comment: I have the feeling you should be filtering by the `and` op (`&`), not the `or` op (`|`).

Comment: @sophocles They are indeed empty strings, I thought notnull would account for that whilst dropna was for values that have the string "NA"?

Comment: @QuangHoang I did try the & operator, but it resulted in 0 rows left, I'm guessing because there is now single row that matches all the criteria (you cannot be DataType "Type 1" AND "Type 2")

Comment: @coghlan 1. the functions with na and null in their name are exactly the same, just alternative names. 2. read documentation on what is considered a nan value in pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data - strings are never nan, because "" is still a string, just with no content.

Comment: @sophocles That was the issue, they were being stored as blank strings because I hadn't specified how I wanted the csv to be saved in the first place

Comment: @JohannesSchöck Thank you for the useful link, I understand where I was going wrong and now it works as intended